# capturing incoming FIX messages which fail QuickFix validation

Tags: quickfix, fix-protocol

A [Quickfix](http://www.quickfixengine.org/) client validates incoming messages using [XML spec files](http://www.quickfixengine.org/documentation). If a message fails validation, quickfix automatically sends a rejection response. AFAIK in this case quickfix does not call the standard callback for incoming messages `fromApp()`, so up till now I was unable to programatically capture these erroneous incoming messages and handle them.

**Is there a way to capture incoming FIX messages which fail quickfix validation?**

Of course they may appear in the default quickfix log files, but I would rather capture them in my code in realtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validation via XML spec file is in session level processing. 
So, **there is not** suitable hook for this.

On the other hand, there are some configuration parameters;

- UseDataDictionary : eliminates validation
- ValidateUserDefinedFields : eliminates user defined field's validation

[look for detailed descriptions](http://www.quickfixengine.org/quickfix/doc/html/configuration.html)

edit: 
If your real problem is monitoring rejections, capturing Reject(3) and BusinessReject(j) messages at toAdmin() hook is sufficient.

Comment: That kind of configuration tweak would only hide the problem.  Not recommended.

Comment: Of course, i did not recommend for production use. I just answered real question that "Is there a way ...".

Comment: I consider it a QuickFix design flaw, thanks for the workaround suggestion

Answer (score 5):

There is not.

QuickFIX simply does not consider this a useful feature.  If a message is invalid, QF performs the protocol-specified behavior and there is nothing that the application could or should do to recover.  Any fix will require developer analysis and xml and/or code fixes, thus log files are sufficient to record the issue.

If you would like an automated alert when such errors occur, I suggest perhaps some kind of external log monitoring app that could watch your logs for occurrences of 35=3 or 35=j.  (On the cheap side, a composition of cron/grep actions could do this very easily.)

Comment: I consider it a QuickFix design flaw, thanks for the workaround suggestion

Comment: A flaw would imply some improper FIX behavior.  At best, you could say this is a missing feature, but it's not one that people are clamoring for.  In my 5 years on the FIX mailing list, I don't think I've ever heard anyone ask for this.

Comment: It's been a problem... it would be good to have a message in the log to say "this has failed XML validation".